# Extensible Data Security in Dynamics Ax

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax7

You need to set up the context for an extensible data security (XDS) policy.
Which security element should you use?

- A. Permission
- B. Duty
- C. Role
- D. Privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C. Role

See [Overview of Security Policies for Table Records](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272123.aspx)  for details.